# Fonts eventually go black in gnome-3 shell

Tags: gnome, themes, fonts, ubuntu-gnome

I can't seem to find any information or similar reports on the net, it's an issue that's quite hard to search for. I'm not even sure how to put what is happening into keywords that google would get right.

This happens consistently after a few hours of use. It only happens in the shell, while all applications (including gtk+ themed menu bars) seem to render fonts perfectly fine.

And once this happens, I have to open gnome tweak tool and go to the font hinting settings and just change it to any other value, which I assume re-renders the fonts.

Any idea on how I can fix this for good?

[image: full screenshot]

Comment: Did you try using another theme, or to revert back to the default (adwita) theme?

Comment: Interesting.. switching to default seems to have expected behavior at least for task bar, but if i switch back to arc dark, it will still show black and still needs to be updated with font smoothing. Now, with default shell theme it seems there is a good amount of black in shell context menus and app selection. Look at this image http://i.imgur.com/n3lNZ8u.png

Comment: In the photo above. You are not using default, are you? Because adwita is more "whitish" and arc theme doesn't work well on 16.10, are you on 16.10?

Comment: Also try changing the icon-pack they can miss up things easily too.

Comment: gnome-tweak-tool has a global dark theme setting. Definitely adwita. Maybe if I disable font hinting it may work. I'll wait and see. The icon packs seemed to make no difference.

Comment: Aha yeah. I never use that. Did try to see if that's the problem??

Comment: Disabling font hinting did nothing :-(

Comment: Global dark theme disabled also no change.

Comment: Well Ibtirer everything you have in my gnome DE. But no such behaviour is happening with me. I would say the easiest way for you would be to install another DE to check if the problem happens there too. If not remove gnome completely and re install it. Or just reinstall your Ubuntu from scratch.